# Trie search with regex: C++

Tags: c++, search, tree, trie

Ok I have to search a Trie tree with input like "*all", where * could be any character. I know that using a regex_match to match a search for a string, like with the other trees, where you're searching a whole word. But since the search algorithm for a Trie goes by characters I am having trouble converting the regular search algorithm to my needs.

Here is the untouched, regular code for a trie search without the *

```
 bool Trie::searchWord(string s){
Node* cur = root;

while(cur != NULL){
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        Node* tmp = cur->findChild(s[i]);
        if(tmp == NULL){
            return false;
        }//end if
        cur = tmp;
    }//end for
    if(cur->wordMarker()){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }//end if-else
}//end while
return false;
}//end searchWord(s)

Node* Node::findChild(char c){
for(int i = 0; i<mChildren.size(); i++){
    Node* tmp = mChildren.at(i);
    if(tmp->content() == c){
        return tmp;
    }//end if
}//end for
return NULL;
}//end findChild(c)
```

Here is my attempt to modify it. It works for regular words still but doesn't work for the *

```
bool Trie::searchWordRegex(string s){
Node* cur = root;

while(cur != NULL){
    regex reg ;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        if(s[i] == '*'){
            reg = regex("(\\w)");
        }//end if
        Node* tmp = cur->findChildRegex(s[i], reg);
        if(tmp == NULL){
            return false;
        }//end if
        cur = tmp;
    }//end for
    if(cur->wordMarker()){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }//end if-else
}//end while
return false;
}//end searchWord(s)

Node* Node::findChildRegex(char c, regex r){
for(int i = 0; i<mChildren.size(); i++){
    Node* tmp = mChildren.at(i);
    string s(1,tmp->content());
    if(tmp->content() == c || regex_match(s, r)){
        return tmp;
    }//end if
}//end for
return NULL;
}//end findChild(c)
```

Is there a way I can fix these functions to work? Or is there as easy way like with the regex_match for the other trees?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The intention is a little confusing since you refer to '*' as a character wildcard, but you refer to regular expression matching (the actual regex character wildcard is '.').  I'll try to answer the question assuming intent is either to support full regular expression searching against a trie, or wildcard searches in a trie.

**Regular Expression Matching in Trie**

A trie is typically used to support fast O(m) operations.  It is not a generally efficient structure for processing regular expressions.

There are a couple algorithms for [regular expression matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Implementations_and_running_times) (DFA/NFA, and backtracking), and to support them within the trie search, you would effectively have to implement one modified to support iteration over sub-tries, and backtracking within the trie for the collection of states/matches the regular expression can match.  This would have lowest asymptotic complexity, potential to be most efficient.

However...

t nearly has the same asymptotic complexity to iterate over all strings in the trie, and test them against a regular expression match using `std::regex` and `std::regex_match`.  Additionally, it saves you from having to implement a regular expression engine, which is relatively complicated.

**Wildcard Matching in Trie**

Modifying your code to support wildcard searches, however, is very simple.  Instead of searching each level with the explicit character, you check the search character `s[i]` against the wildcard ('*', or '.'), and if it matches you can descend into any of the sub-tries, and increment `i`.  Although, there's the caveat that you will need to be able to *escape* whatever character you choose as the wildcard so it remains a valid character in the strings stored in the trie.

Comment: Let me clarify. The input takes in a * to represent that there can be any character there. I am suppose to return all words in the tree that correspond with the sequence. EX: input = *a*, then output would be a list like, hat, cat, bat, can, man... All words with an 'a' in the second position of the string. When I had to search other data structure doing this I used (\\w) to replace the * in the string and turned it into a regex expression to compare to with regex_match. But since the trie deals with characters and not a string I have failed at my attempts to implement that method.

Comment: What you're describing isn't consistent.  If `*` is only a wildcard, how can `a*` match 'hat', 'cat', etc...?  Wouldn't the correct pattern be `*a*`?  However, if `*` does represent a character wildcard (similar to how `\wa\w` would match 'hat', 'cat', etc... with a regular expression) you will want to read the section I wrote for wildcard matching in trie.  Since trie nodes are indexed by character, regular expressions do not apply.  The `*` would be a special kind of lookup in the trie.  Think in terms of which sub-tries are valid for each character in the string.  Normally, it's only one.